# Adding Life Time Sales

Tags: magento, report, admin

I Magento, when you go to Customers -> Manage Customers and you are on the list of all customers, my client wants to add "Lifetime Sales" to this report. Is this possible ?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 2):

There is already something similar in *Reports > Customers > Customers by orders total*.

Note that reports tend to take a long time to render because they are collating a lot of information, the Manage-* pages need to be kept light so I wouldn't like the thought of shoe-horning too much information into those tables. If the *Customers by orders total* report isn't quite right then consider writing a new report - in the reports section - that is better suited.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I will check this out under writing custom reports. This client is a pain so we'll see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to do it. You need to extend that grid.
I recently needed something similar so here is my query to get lifetime sales.

```
$orderStatuses = array(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, Mage_Sales_Model_ORder::STATE_PROCESSING);

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$resourceOrder = $order->getResource();

$select = $readConnection->select()
    ->from(array('sales' => $resourceOrder->getTable('sales/order')), 'SUM(base_subtotal)')
    ->where('sales.customer_id=?', $customer->getId())
    ;
//filter by status
$select->where('state IN (?)', $orderStatuses);
//    echo $select . '<br/>'; exit;

$total = $readConnection->fetchOne($select);
```

You can change orderStatuses array and add whatever suits you.